# Remove highlighting from selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a script that runs if I initiate it from the VBA editor, but not when I initiate it directly from Word.

The script defines acronyms in Word documents. Before the Word file comes to me, it goes through a first-level edit in which the editor highlights terms. Because my script also uses highlighting, I have it replace the existing highlighting with colored text.

```
'Turn track changes off, replace yellow highlighting from FLEs with colored text to avoid confusion between
'FLE highlighting and acronym defininer highlighting
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
    
    .Highlight = True
    
    With .Replacement
    
        .Highlight = False
        .Font.Color = RGB(155, 187, 89)
    
    End With
    
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindStop

End With

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
```

When I run the script from Word, it skips that entire block of code. Everything else works as it should, but the highlighting from the first-level edit remains.

When I run from the VBA editor, everything works as intended.

When I make other changes (e.g., I just updated one of the forms that the macro calls to add an explanation for the green text), they come through, no matter where I starting the script from.

Below is the entire script.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Definitions(5) As String
    
Sub Acronym_Definer()
    'Defines Workbook and Worksheet, Opens Excel
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWbk As Workbook
    Dim FN As String: FN = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Gartner\AcronymDefiner\AcronymDefiner.xlsx"
    
    Dim Current_Row As Long: Current_Row = 2
    
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FN)
    
    'Determines whether Track Changes is on or off so it can be returned to original state at end of macro
    Dim Track_Changes As Boolean
    If ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False Then
    
        Track_Changes = False
    
    End If
    
    'Changes to Simple View in Track Changes to keep deleted text from coming up in searches throughout the macro
    With ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter
        .Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupSimple
        .View = wdRevisionsViewFinal
    End With
    
    'Turn track changes off, replace yellow highlighting from FLEs with colored text to avoid confusion between
    'FLE highlighting and acronym defininer highlighting
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    With Selection.Find
        
        .Highlight = True
        
        With .Replacement
        
            .Highlight = False
            .Font.Color = RGB(155, 187, 89)
        
        End With
        
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    
    End With
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    'Begins acronym definition loop
    Do While Current_Row <= xlWbk.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
        'Use to decide which column to check for NNTD status
        Dim NNTD_Column As Integer
        Dim NNTD As Boolean: NNTD = False
        
        Dim Chosen_Definition As String
        Dim Current_Acronym As String: Current_Acronym = xlWbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Current_Row, 1)
        Dim User_Skip As Boolean
    
        Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    
        With Selection.Find
    
            .ClearFormatting
            '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
            .Text = Current_Acronym
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
    
        End With
        
        'Check for presence of acronym
        If Selection.Find.Execute Then
    
            'How many definitions does this acronym have?
            Dim Number_Definitions As Integer: Number_Definitions = xlWbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Current_Row, 2)
    
            'There's only one definition; the definition is in column 3 and the NNTD status is in column 4
            If Number_Definitions = 1 Then
    
                Chosen_Definition = xlWbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Current_Row, 3)
                NNTD_Column = 4
                NNTD = xlWbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Current_Row, NNTD_Column)
                User_Skip = False
    
            'There's more than one definition; put definitions into array and get definition from user form
            Else
    
                'Ensures Array is empty at start of each loop
                Erase Definitions
    
                'Adds the definitions to Definitions array
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim Current_Column As Integer: Current_Column = 3
    
                For i = 1 To Number_Definitions
    
                    Definitions(i - 1) = xlWbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Current_Row, Current_Column)
                    Current_Column = Current_Column + 2
    
                Next i
    
                'Opens userform to allow user to choose from the available definitions
                Load DefinitionList
                DefinitionList.lstAvailableDefinitions.List = Definitions
                DefinitionList.Show
    
                'Did the user select an option?
                If IsNull(DefinitionList.lstAvailableDefinitions.Value) Then
    
                    User_Skip = True
    
                Else
    
                    'Assigns user selection to Chosen_Definition variable
                    Chosen_Definition = DefinitionList.lstAvailableDefinitions.Value
    
                    User_Skip = False
    
                    'Determines NNTD column
                    Dim j As Integer
                    For j = LBound(Definitions) To UBound(Definitions)
    
                        If Definitions(j) = Chosen_Definition Then
                        NNTD_Column = (2 * j) + 4
                        Exit For
                        End If
    
                    Next j
    
                    Unload DefinitionList
    
                NNTD = xlWbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(Current_Row, NNTD_Column)
                
                End If
    
            End If
            
            'Acronym is NNTD
            If NNTD = True Then
    
                'Highlights NNTD acronyms in yellow.
                Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    
                With Selection.Find
    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Current_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
    
                    With .Replacement
    
                        .Highlight = True
                        .Text = ""
    
                    End With
    
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    
                End With
    
            'User chose to skip or clicked OK without selecting an option; highlight all instances of acronym in red
            ElseIf User_Skip = True Then
    
                Unload DefinitionList
    
                Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    
                With Selection.Find
    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Current_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
    
                    With .Replacement
    
                        .Highlight = True
                        .Text = ""
    
                    End With
    
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    
                End With
            
            'Acronym needs to be defined
            Else
                
                'Selects first instance of acronym. Get start position of first instance of acronym.
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                Selection.Find.Execute Current_Acronym
                Dim AcronymStart As Long: AcronymStart = Selection.Start
                
                'Determines whether definition occurs in document
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                With Selection.Find
    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Chosen_Definition
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop
    
                End With
    
                'Definition doesn't occur; insert definition before first definition of acronym and add
                'parentheses around acronym
                If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
    
                    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    
                    With Selection.Find
    
                        '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                        .Text = Current_Acronym
                        .MatchCase = True
                        .Execute
    
                    End With
    
                    With Selection
    
                        .InsertBefore Chosen_Definition & " ("
                        .InsertAfter ")"
    
                    End With
    
                'Definition occurs in document; get end position of definition and compare to start position of acronym
                '(should be two lower than acronym)
                Else
    
                    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                    Selection.Find.Execute Chosen_Definition
                    Dim DefinitionEnd As Long: DefinitionEnd = Selection.End
    
                    'Acronym is correctly defined; no further action is needed to define the acronym
                    If DefinitionEnd = AcronymStart - 2 Then
    
                    'Definition occurs after acronym; insert definition before first instance of acronym
                    ElseIf DefinitionEnd > AcronymStart Then
    
                        'Moves to first instance of acronym
                        Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    
                        'Adds definition and places parentheses around acronym
                        With Selection.Find
    
                            '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                            .Text = Current_Acronym
                            .MatchCase = True
                            .Execute
    
                        End With
                        
                        With Selection
    
                            .InsertBefore Chosen_Definition & " ("
                            .InsertAfter ")"
    
                        End With
    
                    'Definition occurs before (but not immediately prior to) acronym
                    Else
    
                        Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                        Selection.Find.Execute Chosen_Definition
    
                        'Inserts acronym (surrounded by parentheses) after definition
                        With Selection
    
                            .InsertAfter " (" & Current_Acronym & ")"
    
                        End With
    
                    End If
    
                End If
    
                'Replace subsequent instances of acronym *and* definition with just acronym
                Dim Defined_Acronym As String: Defined_Acronym = Chosen_Definition & " (" & Current_Acronym & ")"
    
                'Moves cursor to follow first instance of Defined_Acronym
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                
                With Selection.Find
                    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Defined_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Execute
                    
                End With
    
                'Performs actual replacement of all but first instance of Defined_Acronym with acronym.
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                
                With Selection.Find
                    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Defined_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Execute
                    
                End With
                
                Selection.EndOf unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdMove
                
                With Selection.Find
    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Defined_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = False
                    
                    With .Replacement
                        
                        .Highlight = False
                        .Text = Current_Acronym
                        
                    End With
                    
                    .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    
                End With
    
    
                'Replace subsequent instances of definition (by itself) with acronym
                'Moves cursor to follow first instance of Defined_Acronym
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                
                With Selection.Find
    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Defined_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Execute
                    
                End With
                
                Selection.EndOf unit:=wdWord, Extend:=wdMove
                
                With Selection.Find
    
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Chosen_Definition
                    .MatchCase = False
                    
                    
                    With .Replacement
                    
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Text = Current_Acronym
                        
                    End With
                    
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindStop
                    
                End With
    
                'Set highlight color to teal for non-NNTD acronyms, highlight all instances of Current_Acronym
                Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdTeal
                Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
                
                With Selection.Find
    
                    .ClearFormatting
                    '.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
                    .Text = Current_Acronym
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
    
                    With .Replacement
    
                        .Highlight = True
                        .Text = ""
    
                    End With
    
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindStop
    
                End With
        
            End If
        
        End If
    
        'Ends acronym definition loop
        Current_Row = Current_Row + 1
            
    Loop
    
    'Returns track changes to same status it was in when script began
    If Track_Changes = False Then
    
        ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    
    End If
    
    'Returns view to show all track changes
    With ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter
        .Markup = wdRevisionsMarkupAll
        .View = wdRevisionsViewFinal
    End With
    
    Load Instructions
    Instructions.Show
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    
    'Closes Excel
    xlWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    xlApp.Quit
    
End Sub
    
Function Define_Acronym()
    
End Function
```

Comment: I would recommend specifying the range instead of using the selection. For example `ActiveDocument.Range` instead of `Selection`

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how you call the macro a Selection may not exist at first. Bear in mind that `Selection.Find` essentially means "Find [whatever] in the range specified by the current selection". Seeing that you collapse the selection to nothing with `Selection.Homekey Unit:=WdStory` I tried to figure out why your code works at all and failed. For some reason best known to itself Word seems to agree to search the entire document when the selection is 0 (or 1). But zero isn't the same as Nothing.

The better way is to specify the Range or Selection you wish to search. Either way it should be `ActiveDocument.Content` if you wish to search the entire body of the document. While your code is based on using the Selection object you must make such a selection, for example, `ActiveDocument.Content.Select`.

@Slai and I would recommend not to use the Selection object at all. Use a Range object instead. Read about the difference [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211953(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Next time I have a chance to work on this, I'll see about switching things around. Since I use the selection.homekey so much, I'll have to refactor quite a bit. I'll update at that point.